# Reducing output of script

Tags: powershell

I have a script that will report on windows event logs and email the message of said event. the issue is sometimes there can be a lot of detail in the message which means the email is overwhelmed with nonsense. What i would like to do is take a snippet for example the first 10 words of the message.. (the foreground red also doesn't work in the email)

**Update** The below code works to split everything to a new line but it seems that the $event.message returns the first log in the event log as opposed to the message of the error in the if statement;

```
 $body += Write-Output "Server $server has an error: " $($event.Message -split '\n')[0]  `n
```

With regards to HTML, if I put HTML body at the beginning and the end of the code where within the foreach statement would the formatting go?

```cs
foreach ($server in $servers) { 
    $event = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName "system"  -Newest 200

    if ($event.Source.Contains("Ntfs") -or $event.Source.Contains("DistributedCOM")) {  
        $body += Write-Output "Server $server has an error: " $($event.Message -split '\n')[0]  `n  
    } else { 
        $body += Write-Output "Server $server has nothing to report           `n"
    }
```

Comment: May I suggest that you immerse yourself in a PowerShell tutorial and get accustomed to how PowerShell operators and string handling in general work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume as you're already splitting `$event.Message` on new-line that it's a multi-line message.

You can select just the first line of that message with a minor change to your code:

```
Write-Output "Server $server has an error:" ($event.Message -split '\n')[0]
```

Comment: Thank you James, will this split the messages out as opposed to return part of the entire message?

Comment: Only the first line: `-split '\n'` creates an array (each line as an entry), then we select the first entry (first line) using `[0]`

Comment: Thanks James, do you know how i can return the message i care about instead of the first available message.

Comment: You'd need to ask a new question for that as it's more code than comments should be used for,

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$event.Message -split '\n'
```

to

```
($event.Message | Out-String) -replace '^((?:\s*\S+){1,10}).*', '$1'
```

And `-ForegroundColor Red` won't work anywhere, because a) `Write-Output` has no such parameter, and b) plain e-mail doesn't support color in the first place (you'd need HTML e-mail for that).

Comment: Thank you, that has certainly helped, the output is far more usebale and on each line however it has just appended the -replace etc to the end of the message.
I played around with using <html><body> etc but.. no joy and apologies i thought it was write-host that didn't have the parameter.

Comment: @richb If the above code didn't do what you want please update your question with a more complete sample of the code you currently have as well as an example of desired and actual output.